# Oracle sum of columns based on conditions

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get sum of PREFIX_RSDL_PRORTDCST, PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST, PARTCODE_RSDL_PRORTDSUM, PARTCODE_FRINGE_RSDL_AMT but it based on some conditions.

```
SELECT PP.PP_STATUS_CD
     , PP.PF_STATUS_CD
     , PCP.PCP_STATUS_CD
     , PCP.PCF_PRORTD_STATUS_CD
     , PP.PREFIX_RSDL_PRORTDCST
     , PP.PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST
     , PCP.PARTCODE_RSDL_PRORTDSUM
     , PCP.PARTCODE_FRINGE_RSDL_AMT
     , COALESCE(PP.PREFIX_RSDL_PRORTDCST, 0) 
       + COALESCE(PP.PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST, 0) 
       + COALESCE(PCP.PARTCODE_RSDL_PRORTDSUM, 0) 
       + COALESCE(PCP.PARTCODE_FRINGE_RSDL_AMT, 0) AS TOTAL_UNBILLED_AMOUNT 
FROM FPM_EIMS_CB_PREFIX_PRORTNS  PP 
INNER JOIN FPM_EIMS_CB_CALCULATIONS EC ON PP.PREFIX_PRORTN_ID = EC.PREFIX_PRORTN_ID INNER JOIN FPM_EIMS_CB_FED_SUM_PRORTNS PCP ON PCP.PARTCODE_PRORTN_SUM_ID = EC.PARTCODE_PRORTN_SUM_ID 
INNER JOIN FPM_CB_LEDGER CBL ON CBL.LEDGER_ID = EC.LEDGER_ID
```

If PP_STATUS_CD value is 1097 then include PREFIX_RSDL_PRORTDCST and if PF_STATUS_CD value is 1097 then include PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST and if PCP_STATUS_CD  value is 1097 then include PARTCODE_RSDL_PRORTDSUM and if PCF_PRORTD_STATUS_CD value is 1097 then include PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use `CASE`

e.g.

```
, case 
    when PP_STATUS_CD = 1097 then
       COALESCE(PP.PREFIX_RSDL_PRORTDCST, 0) 
    else 0
  end   
  +
  case 
    when PF_STATUS_CD = 1097 then
       COALESCE(PP.PREFIX_FRNG_RSDL_PRORTDCST, 0) 
    else 0
  end
  +
  case 
    when PCP_STATUS_CD = 1097 then
       COALESCE(PCP.PARTCODE_RSDL_PRORTDSUM, 0) 
    else 0
  end
  +
  case 
    when PCF_PRORTD_STATUS_CD = 1097 then
       COALESCE(PCP.PARTCODE_FRINGE_RSDL_AMT, 0)
    else 0
  end AS TOTAL_UNBILLED_AMOUNT
```